# Apply Customize constraint in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following table in SQL Server

```
  Create Table Banners
    (
    BannerID int Identity(1,1),
    BannerUrl nvarchar(500),
    BannerIsDomestic bit,
    BannerName nvarchar(50),
    CreationDate datetime,
    ModificationDate datetime,
    Show_Status bit,
    Remark nvarchar(500)
    Constraint Banner_ID_PK Primary Key (BannerID)
    )
```

In this I want to apply a customize constraint like, at one time only two rows can have `Show_Status`  to be true. One with `BannerIsDomestic = true` and one with `BannerIsDomestic = false`.

For all the rows that have `BannerIsDomestic = true` only one can have `Show_Status = True` and all other must be false.

And for all the rows that have `BannerIsDomestic = false` only one can have `Show_Status = True`, all others must be false.

Can I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Other than triggers, I don't think there's any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the requirements correctly, this should be achievable with [filtered indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE Banners
    (
    BannerID int Identity(1,1),
    BannerUrl nvarchar(500),
    BannerIsDomestic bit,
    BannerName nvarchar(50),
    CreationDate datetime,
    ModificationDate datetime,
    Show_Status bit,
    Remark nvarchar(500)
    Constraint Banner_ID_PK Primary Key (BannerID)
    )

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Banners_IsDomesticTrue 
ON Banners (BannerIsDomestic) WHERE Show_Status = 1 

INSERT Banners (BannerIsDomestic, BannerName, Show_Status) 
VALUES (1, 'DomesticBannerShow', 1), (1, 'DomesticBannerHide', 0), 
(0, 'ItnlBannerShow', 1), (0, 'IntlBannerHide', 0) 

-- This will fail
INSERT Banners (BannerIsDomestic, BannerName, Show_Status) 
VALUES (1, 'DomesticBanner2', 1)

-- This will fail
INSERT Banners (BannerIsDomestic, BannerName, Show_Status)  
VALUES (0, 'IntlBanners2', 1)
```

Comment: A single simpler filtered index will suffice - `ON Banners (BannerIsDomestic) WHERE Show_Status = 1`.

Comment: I felt clever for a second there. Edited answer as @Damien's observation is correct.